# Вытащить из строки первые цифры и буквенные значения через Stream API

Tags: java-stream

Доброго времени суток!

```
Region(Long id, String name)
```

Есть у меня

```
List<String> bufreg = new ArrayList<>();
bufreg(0) = "1. EU/"
bufreg(1) = "2. RU/"
bufreg(2) = "3. ASIA/"
```

Как мне через Stream пройтись по каждому элементу списка bufreg, и создать новый список, в котором мы возьмем порядковый номер и запишем его в id, а буквы запишем в поле name:

```
new Region(1, "EU");
new Region(2, "RU");
new Region(3, "ASIA");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Region> regions = bufreg.stream()
    .map(i -> i.split("."))
    .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
    .map(a -> new Region(Long.valueOf(a[0]), a[1].trim()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: NPE
 at Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:37)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)

Comment: @Tunix в 37-й строке небось первый map? Тогда у вас в bufreg есть элементы, содержащие null. Если это штатная ситуация, то нужно добавить шаг фильтрации.